# Textbook has a strange section on absolute value that I don't quite understand

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

My textbook says $|a| = -a$ for $a \le 0$.

> [image]

What does it mean by this? I'm confused and think that the absolute value of a negative number like $|-5|$ would be positive $5$?

Comment: But $5$ is indeed $-(-5)$.

Comment: Yea, I figured it was some small detail like that just don't have an intuitive grasp of it. So basically its a way of retaining the sign for the original value and you would think of it like -(-5)? That makes sense, thanks @lulu

Comment: $-a$ does not mean "a number that is negative."  It means "the additive inverse (or 'opposite') of $a$".  The opposite of a negative number is a positive number.  So if $a < 0$ (i.e. $a$ is negative), then $-a > 0$ (i.e. $-a$ is positive).

Comment: Ahh ok I think I understand the concept more now. Thanks @XanderHenderson. I'm new to this site so not sure if I need to approve these answers or show my thanks by giving a rating but I appreciate the help.

Comment: The absolute value is the "non-negative magnitude".  If $a > 0$ then $|a| = a>0$.  But if $a < 0$ then notice that $-a > 0$.  So that means that $-a$ is be *positive* magnitude and $a< 0$ is the *negative* magnitude.

Comment: Yeah, for me the trick is realizing that if $a < 0$ then $-a$ ***IS*** a positive number (but only if $a < 0$. If $a > 0$ then $-a$ is negative and if $a=0$ then $-a = a = 0$.)

Comment: You might think of the absolute value of a number as the distance away from zero (which has helped my intuition). $-5$ is therefore five units way from zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct $|-5| = 5$.  *BUT* notice if $a = -5$ then $-a = -(-5) = 5$.

Think of it this way.  If $a < 0$ then $|a|$ is positive and $a$ is negative.  So $|a|$ is the *opposite* of $a$.  So $|a| = -a$ because $-a$ is the opposite of $a$.

In short.  An negative sign before a variable does *not* mean the number is negative.  It means the number is the opposite sign of whatever the variable means.

To beat a dead horse:  If $a \ge 0$ then $|a| > 0$.  But if $a < 0$ then $|a|$ would be "whatever it takes to make $a$ positive" which is, as "a negative of a negative is a positive" must be the *other* direction and that is $-a$.  And we *know*  $-a > 0$.

.... or in yet another way....

The absolute value is the "non-negative magnitude".  If $a > 0$ then $|a| = a>0$.  But if $a < 0$ then notice that $-a > 0$.  So that means that $-a$ ***IS*** the *positive* magnitude and because $a< 0$, then $a$ is the *negative* magnitude.

So $|a| = -a$.

Which is intuitively the opposite of what we think.  Your confusion is understandable and common.  But logically unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! Helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition

- for $x\ge 0$ we have $|x|=x$
- for $x< 0$ we have $|x|=-x$

we have

- $|5|=5$
- $|-5|=-(-5)=5$

therefore $|x|$ is always non negative.

Answer (score 0):

For $a \le 0$, we indeed have $|a| = (-1)(a)$. You want to try $a=-5$, so we have

$$|\underbrace{-5}_{a}|=|a|= (-1) \ \underbrace{(a)}_{a=-5}=-(-5)=5$$

Don't forget, $a$ isn't always positive.

- For positive numbers, the absolute value of $a$ is given by multiplying $1$ with $a$. Eg $|5|=(1)(5)=5$. So, for positive numbers, the absolute value of $a$ is itself.
- For negative numbers, the absolute value of $a$ is given by multiplying by $-1$ with $a$. Eg $|-5|=(-1)(-5)=5$. So, for negative numbers, the absolute value of $a$ is $-a$.